# Android View.draw(canvas) causes colour inconsistency

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to take a'screenshot' of a view and then using it again in a different activity. The problem is that specific colours seem to get messed up when I do.

Additional notes:

- The images consist of a grey base image, with red or green on an overlay image with an alpha value.

  - The view is shown in the parent view by setting it with an inflator. In other words, I have a layout, and within it I have a section

  `<!-- THIS GUY HERE needs to be set to show the correct view.-->
  <RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/my_id" />`

and in the activity I then load the correct view like so:

```
imagesLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_id);
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)
            this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
layoutInflater.inflate(getContentViewID(), imagesLayout);
```

Here is my code to create the image:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(),
view.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas bitmapHolder = new Canvas(bitmap);
view.draw(bitmapHolder);
return bitmap;
```

and this is the result (smaller image is incorrect, larger one is the view):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can save the instance of the layout and save it as your bitmap.

Comment: Hi there! Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean (I'm still very much a newbie)? Is there some documentation or something I can look at?

Comment: O, just the normal saveInstanceState? The problem is that the layout I'm trying to create a bitmap from is inside another layout. I'll update my question to expand on this a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!! It turns out, instead of using ARGB_8888, I needed to use RGB_565. Figured it out with the help of this article: http://android.nakatome.net/2010/04/bitmap-basics.html

Really hopes this helps someone else out in the  future.

Comment: OK wait, it only solved some cases. Any other suggestions?

Comment: It seems the problem was that my RED value was too high on the overlay. So brighter parts would cause the image to go blue. I lowered the R value, and it seems to be working fine now (with both RGB565 and ARGB8888)